# Easy way to generate XML Documentation on Visual Studio Web Project

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, documentation

There is no "build" tab in properties for a web project in Visual Studio 2010 for C# compiling. Is there a way to generate the XML Documentation for c# code in the web project without modifying the webconfig file?

I have tried to do this method : http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/94c7f744-9b90-4254-93ab-9b15f47d9f42.htm

But I get the following error: `gacutil : The term 'gacutil' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

When I try to register EWSoftware.CodeDom.dll assembly in the GAC

Comment: Well what happened when you tried the solution in the linked article? Why do you need a different solution?

Comment: I made an edit to the question. I also am trying to find a way that does not involve me changing the webconfig file.

Comment: how did you get this to work with sandcastle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Microsoft Tool for generating MSDN Style Documentation called [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/).

It bases the class/property descriptions off of the XML comments in your code such as this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of Method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="GroupID">Description of GroupID Parameter</param>
    /// <returns>Description of return value</returns>
```